# Sublime Text 3 Syntax Colouring issues with Javascript and ESLint

Tags: javascript, react-native, sublimetext3, jsx

I'm following a Udemy course on React Native, using Sublime Text 3 and ESLint code is being highlighted seemingly incorrectly.

Does anybody know how to fix this to make it more consistent?[image]

Note the comment on line 11 not being faded out, and the  tags being different colours.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: At the bottom right corner of Sublime, what does it say? What language syntax are you using?

Comment: better switch with [`atom`](https://atom.io/) easy to hack able editor

Comment: @LazarNikolic javascript

Comment: Try selecting react or react native instead

Comment: @user568458 in the course I'm following that isn't mentioned, tried it and it colours the entire statement inside the quotes.

Comment: @LazarNikolic they aren't options, or at least I couldn't find them?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, installed the Babel package. Then set the syntax to Javascript(Babel) and it's all sorted.